# how to pause mp3 using mediaplayer in another activity when an item is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

i'm make mp3 player offline, in the MainActivity there is a song list when an item is clicked it will send the song data with intent to PlayActivity. I want when another song is clicked then the current song is paused. What should i do? below is my code

`MainActivity`

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
//deklarasi variabel -->
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
ListView listView;
final String[] song_name = { "intuisi", "krisis solusi" };
final int[] ResID = {R.raw.intuisi, R.raw.krisis};
ImageView img_play;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //inisialisasi variabel
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_item);

    //make adapter for listview
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, song_name);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //onClick item
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            playSong(i);

        }
    });
}

private void playSong(int songIndex) {
    //send song data to playActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Play.class);
    intent.putExtra("song", ResID[songIndex]);
    startActivity(intent);
```

}

`PlayActivity`

int Nama = getIntent().getIntExtra("song",0);

```
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Nama);

    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate singleton helper class for handling your music player with some contextual method like play, pause, stop etc.

```
public class MusicHelper {
    private static MusicHelper instance;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private MusicHelper() {
        instance = new MusicHelper();
    }

    public static MusicHelper getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void init(Context ctx, int nama) {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), nama);
    }

    public void play() {
        if (mPlayer != null && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (mPlayer!= null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

}
```

Then in your PlayActivity,

```
MusicHelper musicHelper = MusicHelper.getInstance();
musicHelper.init(getApplicationContext(), Nama);
musicHelper.play();
```

When clicked on another item, again fetch the helper instance and call pause.

```
private void playSong(int songIndex) {
    MusicHelper musicHelper = MusicHelper.getInstance();
    musicHelper.pause();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Play.class);
    intent.putExtra("song", ResID[songIndex]);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: thanks Maddy Blacklisted, but why I cant call getApplicationContext() in musicHelper ?

Comment: in PlayActivity from where var Nama ?

Comment: As musicHelper is your custom Helper class (Not android contextual class). If you want to get Application Context without passing it as a reference, you would probably need to convert the helper into an Intent Service. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService for implementation.